# cant run executables in ubuntu mate 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mate

Ive tried to run both XAMPP and Copy (file synch software) from the terminal, but whenever I try to execute it, nothing happens, no warning, just a new line for me to type commands on.

With Copy, when I try to click the executable in the x86 folder, (yes it is the linux version) nothing happens, nothing.

I just installed ubuntu MATE today and these programs are really important for me so if anybody can help me out it would be very nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it as follow.

The 5.x versions of XAMPP are not working in Ubuntu 14.04, the older 1.8.3 however works perfectly fine. Use this, avoid the later ones for now.

As for Copy, download it through an alternative repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/copy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install copy
```

Answer (score 0):

When running from the terminal, insure that what you want to run is on your path, if not, insure that it's in the folder you are in by issuing the command `ls programname` and if it does exist there you can launch it with `./programname`